# Force base class virtual method call inside of base class

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance

**Don't get me wrong: I do not want to force an overriding method to call the base class like already asked 1000...times before :)**

I wondered if there is any way to force the call of the base class implementation of a method inside the base class.

Example:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var c = new SubClass();
        c.CallInfo();
    }

    internal class BaseClass {
        protected virtual void Info(){
            Console.WriteLine("BaseClass");
        }

        internal virtual void CallInfo() {
            this.Info();
        }
    }

    internal class SubClass : BaseClass {
        protected override void Info() {
            Console.WriteLine("SubClass");
        }

        internal override void CallInfo() {
            base.CallInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

Output obviously would be `SubClass`. Is there any way to force the `CallInfo` method of `BaseClass` to call its own `Info` method so that the output would be `BaseClass`?

Comment: you can create a constructor for base class to call Info() of itself during its creation.  However, can you clarify what you are really trying to accomplish?  Expected output.  Do you want to see BOTH WriteLine() content of Subclass AND BaseClass?  Important or not for the BaseClass to be done first, then Subclass?

Comment: No, as by bold font comment clearyfies: I do not want to force any base method call from sub class. Just forcing the call of the virtual base method from within other base methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By marking your `Info()` method as `virtual` you are specifically asking for this type of inheritance behaviour to occur.

If you want to ensure that a method call in your base class is not overridden, you'll need to use a non-virtual method, e.g.

```
internal class BaseClass {
    protected virtual void Info(){
        this.FinalInfo();
    }

    protected void FinalInfo() {
        Console.WriteLine("BaseClass");
    }

    internal virtual void CallInfo() {
        this.FinalInfo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the virtual keyword. This "workaround" is obvious to me, but i was wondering if there isn't any other way to achieve what I want.

Comment: @infotoni91, what is so bad about this approach that you are looking for "another way"? What makes you uncomfortable/hesitant about the approach shown in the answer here?

Comment: The fact that I would have to polute many methods like this into the base class. There are several methods that I would end up guarding somehow like this to achieve certainity.

Comment: @infotoni91, if you have to do this for many methods as you say, then you seem to have a flaw in your type/class design. Probably worth rethinking the design and structuring of your type hierarchies...

Comment: It's a huge project 1.5 MLOC and for one very specific case I'm injecting the SubClass through the EntityFramework to replace and extend the BaseClass. The actual design is stable and consistent, but I'm planing and designing my module right now and THERE are some inconsistencies left I think :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that. The purpose of virtual methods is that derived classes can override the implementation and that the implementation is used even when called it from base classes.

If that causes problems then the method you want to run should not be a virtual method.

This would work, while it won't force an implementation by a subclass like virtual it'll allow you to override it.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var c = new SubClass();
        c.CallInfo();
    }

    internal class BaseClass
    {
        protected void Info()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BaseClass");
        }

        internal virtual void CallInfo()
        {
            this.Info();
        }
    }

    internal class SubClass : BaseClass
    {  
        protected new void Info()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SubClass");
        }

        internal override void CallInfo()
        {
            base.CallInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Member hiding is not equivalent to overriding a (virtual) method. As such, your answer does not really match the context of the question.

Comment: @elgonzo What he wants to do is not possible, so this would be an alternative if he really needs to use this structure.

Comment: I did not argue that what OP wanted is not possible. Of course it is not. But member hiding is not the answer (as it will change the "behavior" of the method call resolution for the hidden method...). Note that OP only asked that they want to call a base class method **from within the base class itself**. However, your answer changes if and when the Info method of SubClass is being called **outside**! of that context.

Comment: (Btw, note keiwan's answer, which achieves the desired behavior without changing the "behavior" of the method call resolution for the Info method outside of the requested context.)

Comment: Thanks, but the now edited code doesn't meet my original logic, as there is no callable member Info which gives "SubClass".

Comment: @infotoni91, the chosen method names here are just a cosmetic naming "issue". To adapt and change the method names chosen in this answer according to your needs shouldn't really be a problem...

Comment: @elgonzo no, simply one method was missing up to now ;)

Comment: Oh sorry, i didn't notice the missing method. My bad, my apologies. But with the latest edit we are back at the member hiding scenario (which i pointed out in my first comment), with the difference of this time omitting the `new` keyword (and thus producing a compiler warning). Anyway, i sign off now. I don't want to endlessly ramble about this... ;-)